# Calling a variable that was created in a function as a string in a different function

Tags: python, function, variables, global

I'm quite new to python and I keep getting an error saying that "dest_choice is `not defined"

```
def flight_choice():
    destination_option = input ("Where do you wnat to go?\n[1] Spain\n [2] Paris")
if destination_option == "1":
dest_choice = "Spain"
```

then called upon later with

```
def ticket_amount():
    print("The flight you selected was to" + str(dest_choice) + "Thanks for flying with us"
```

I'm fairly sure I need to use either "global" or "nonlocal" but I can figure out what with

Comment: That is a duplicate, but I wouldn't advocate the use of globals. Just return the string to the caller.